# Get element background-size in css

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have a background element with a css like this:

```
.header-section {
    background      : url('images/siam/home-test.png') no-repeat scroll center center;
    background-size : cover;
}
```

Next I want to get this element background size to set in on a form that will blur this background. So the form css is:

```
.form-test {
    position        : absolute;
    background-image:url("images/siam/home-test-blur.png");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    @include background-size(cover);
    background-attachment: fixed;

    &.tinted{
        @include background-image(linear-gradient(0deg, transparent,rgba(30, 33, 39,.2)),url("images/siam/home-test-blur.png"));
    }
    &.shaded{
        @include background-image(linear-gradient(0deg,  transparent,rgba(30, 33, 39,.2)),url("images/siam/home-test-blur.png"));
    }   
}

.form-test {
    border        : 1px solid #3B3B3B;
    padding       : 15px 50px;
    top           : -27px;
    width         : 650px;
    z-index       : 1;
    font-family   : 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 12px 18px 0px rgba(0, 9, 22,.9);
    box-shadow: 0 12px 18px 0px rgba(0, 9, 22,.9);
}
```

but the `@include background-size(cover);` get's an incorect size, and I think because I have other element with `background-size: cover` set. The question is how can I set the `background-size` of `.form-test` from `.header-section` -`background-size`
The effect I want to achieve is something like this: [Open in CodePen](https://codepen.io/ariona/pen/geFIK/)

Comment: even setting it with jquery does not help:
`$(function(){
 var width = $('.header-section2').width()+' px';
 var height = $('.header-section2').height()+' px';
 console.log(width + ', ' + height);
 $('#form-test10').css("background-size", width + ', ' + height);
 
});`

Comment: The CodePen you included is using compass `@import "compass/css3";` and SCSS to achieve this effect, the `@include background-size(cover);` is a mixin built into compass. verify that you are including compass in your project and the SCSS file is properly compiled.

Comment: yup, I don't have that. googling how to install compass I have left this idea..Next I think to add the blurred image as a background to the form and set the background-size to the size of header background. But how can I get the header backgroun-size?